# D'où vient l'expression « in catalogue » et que veut elle dire ?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, latin

Je pense la question est assez claire.

Voici une phrase à titre d'exemple :

> Joël Stein *in* Catalogue de l'exposition 72, douze ans d'art contemporain en France...

ou bien:

> V. Vasarely *in* catalogue de l'exposition *Lumière et mouvement*, Musée d'art moderne de la Ville de Paris, 1967.

Une origine précise serait super !

Et bonus: pourquoi dans la phrase ci-dessus catalogue commence avec une majuscule ?

Comment: Une autre précision, je ne sais pas si c'est la source de l'interrogation mais une exposition artistique un peu importante est généralement accompagnée d'une sorte de livre, appelé “catalogue” qui reproduit les œuvres exposées et les complète d'une documentation critique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il y a une variété de normes. Voici quelques observations sur le sujet, en partie dans le même sens qu'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16579/3177).

---

Généralement, le *in* (en italique)/[dans](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3242)(sans italique) est utilisé pour marquer la partie d'une œuvre, un chapitre, ou la contribution au collectif etc. :

> Une notice bibliographique peut porter sur une partie d’un livre
>   plutôt que sur le livre complet [...]
>
> > Ferron, Jacques. « Une fâcheuse compagnie », *Contes*, Montréal,
> >     Bibliothèque québécoise, 1993, p. 60-63.
>
> On peut juger plus clair d’employer la préposition **dans**, ou le mot
>   latin *in*, lorsque l’auteur de la partie et celui de l’ouvrage ne sont
>   pas la même personne. Le nom de l’auteur de l’ouvrage s’écrit alors
>   sans inversion :
>
> > Jacob, Suzanne. « Le réveillon », *in* François Gallays, *Anthologie
> >     de la nouvelle au Québec*,
>
> Certains généralisent à tous les cas cet emploi de *dans* ou de *in* :
>
> > Normand, X. « Pétrole : le raffinage », dans *Encyclopædia Universalis*,
> >     Paris, Encyclopædia Universalis, 1972, vol. 11, p. 882-886.
>
> [ *Termium* (la banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques du
>   gouvernement du Canada), [*Les notices bibliographiques*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect12&info0=12.4.4#zz12) (12.4.4
>   *Partie d’un livre*), extraits ]

Dans *Le lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale* (*Imprimerie nationale*, France, 2002) on ne traite pas de *catalogue*. À l'entrée *bibliographie* en page 33 on étaye entre autres la *contribution à un ouvrage collectif* avec un exemple où *dans* est utilisé tel que précédemment dans le troisième exemple.

---

En règle générale, en typographie, on utilise au moins la majuscule avec le premier substantif du nom d'une manifestation culturelle (*l'Exposition universelle* ; [*Orthotypo*](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/madame-mythologie.html), [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=exposition&cur=2&nmbr=4&lettr=3&info0=3.3.24#zz3), [*BDL*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1314), *Ldreualn*). Certains choix de styles peuvent le refléter.

---

Il ne s'agit pas d'un [*catalogue de produits*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4905) (ni [*de bibliothèque*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4919)), mais on peut être influencé par ce genre de notice où parfois le mot *catalogue*, premier dans un titre, prend la majuscule.

Dans le même ordre d'idées, il faut noter que le nom du catalogue/de l'exposition contient [probablement](https://books.google.com/books?id=vkAqVmZTsWkC&lpg=PA124&dq=72%2C%20douze%20ans%20d'art%20contemporain%20en%20France&hl=fr&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q=72,%20douze%20ans%20d'art%20contemporain%20en%20France&f=false) le nombre *72* ou *72/12* ; d'ailleurs *72* est en italique dans le [document](https://ec56229aec51f1baff1d-185c3068e22352c56024573e929788ff.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/attachments/original/2/8/4/002742284.pdf) dont on extrait fort probablement des *marges* ces notices.

---

*Quelques exemples de styles*

Sur le site du *Ministère de la Culture et de la Communication du Gouvernement de la République française*, on trouve des exemples plus ou moins récents de styles fort élaborés. On réfère parfois à AFNOR/[ISO 690](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_690). Voici un exemple dans le domaine de l'[*archéologie*](http://www.culture.gouv.fr/culture/dp/daf_archeo/documents_pdf/Recommandations/Normes%20bibliographiques.pdf) ; on n'emploie pas du tout le mot *catalogue* et on se concentre sur le titre et l'auteur de l'œuvre :

> *8 – Contribution dans un catalogue d’exposition*
>
> **Premier élément-date :** AUTEUR(S) CONTRIBUTION. — Titre contribution : sous-titre contribution. In : AUTEUR(S) DIRECTEUR(S) DU
>   CATALOGUE. — *Titre : sous-titre du catalogue* : lieu, date
>   d’exposition. Lieu : éditeur, année de publication du catalogue,
>   passage. Notes.
>
> ---
>
> *2.2  Référence bibliographique d’une contribution dans une monographie*
>
> PAINTER (K.). — 75. Coupe à collerette. *In* : *Trésors d’orfèvrerie
>   gallo-romains* : exposition Paris-Lyon, Musée du Luxembourg-Musée de
>   la civilisation gallo-romaine 1989. Paris : RMN, 1989, p. 128.
>
> [dans cet exemple] c’est le numéro et l’intitulé d’une notice de
>   catalogue d’exposition qui sont assimilés à un titre de contribution.
>
> *Ministère de la Culture et de la Communication du Gouvernement de la République française*, Établissement des références bibliographiques
>   recommandations minimales, Archéologie de France, 1994

Dans un autre [document](http://www.culture.gouv.fr/culture/inventai/presenta/normes/constit_normesbiblio.pdf), on traite aussi du *catalogue d'exposition*, et on propose deux exemples dont:

> [Exposition. Beauvais. 1994]. **Les Greber, une dynastie d'artistes**
>   :  exposition présentée à Beauvais, du 3 mai-15 sept. 1994. Réd. Jean
>   Cartier, Josette Galiègue, Wilhem Meusburger, et al. Beauvais : Musée
>   départemental de l'Oise, 1993. 396 p. ISBN 2-901290-10-8.
>
> *Ministère de la Culture et de la Communication du Gouvernement de la République française*, Constitution de références bibliographiques,
>   2001

Sur un site d'assistance relié au domaine [universitaire](http://www.ebsi.umontreal.ca/jetrouve/referenc/list_doc.htm) au Québec (voir aussi [uqam](http://www.er.uqam.ca/nobel/r14310/Guide/8.3.html) ; et un [exemple](http://sites.uclouvain.be/infosphere/fichiers_communs/module7/catalogue.html) en Belgique), on trouve:

> *Le théâtre jeune public : l'art des rencontres* (2005) [catalogue d'exposition]. (Exposition : Grande Bibliothèque, Espace Jeunes, 30
>   avril - 31 décembre 2005). Montréal : BNQ, 40 p.

---

Il n'existe pas nécessairement d'expression *in catalogue* en notice bibliographique. Dans les exemples, on veut bien appuyer qu'il s'agisse d'un *catalogue d'exposition* suivi du nom de l'exposition et on utilise ce style. Mais il s'agit d'une référence claire au type d’œuvre (à moins que ça soit formellement au titre). Alors que dans/*in* réfèrent davantage au *titre* et à l'*auteur* d'une œuvre qu'à son *type*. Dans les exemples de la question, on réfère d'abord au type qu'on intercale avant le titre. Dans un exemple en réponse, on utilise des crochets ([catalogue d'exposition]) permettant à cette identification du type de prendre la place d'un commentaire interprétatif qui n'affecte pas l'identification des autres éléments. C'est sans doute une question de choix et d'usage, en fonction des objectifs poursuivis dans un domaine ou contexte particulier.

À mon avis, la majuscule du premier exemple manque de cohérence vu l'ensemble du document source : l'emploi ne semble pas conforme aux autres notices qu'il contient et interfère avec l'idée que c'est le titre qui débute avec une majuscule. En fait l'italique manquant en question, personne n'a exactement identifié le titre (*72, douze ans d'art contemporain en France* ; *catalogue* n'en fait pas partie).

Comment: Merci ça me semble plus logique!

Answer (score 4):

Dans votre exemple, c'est manifestement un style de bibliographie normalisé comme il en existe plusieurs dans le monde académique. Dans ce contexte, « in » vient peut-être de l'anglais ou peut-être du latin mais est apparemment utilisé avant chaque titre d'ouvrage collectif. Vous noterez que « in » est utilisé pour nombre d'autres ouvrages qui ne sont pas des catalogues, mais pas pour tous.

Il est en outre relativement courant que certains ouvrages n'aient pas de titre à proprement parler et dans ce cas là, on les cite comme « Catalogue de telle ou telle exposition » ou « Actes de telle ou telle conférence ».

Donc, nonobstant la typographie un peu aléatoire,

> Joël Stein in Catalogue de l'exposition 72, *douze ans d'art contemporain en France*

signifie probablement que l'on cite quelque chose que Joël Stein a écrit dans le catalogue de l'exposition 72, intitulé *douze ans d'art contemporain en France* mais qu'il n'est pas l'auteur du catalogue en entier. Ou alors il y a une erreur de typographie et il faudrait lire

> Joël Stein in *Catalogue de l'exposition 72, douze ans d'art contemporain en France*

et on peut considérer que « Catalogue de l'exposition 72, douze ans d'art contemporain en France » est le titre de l'ouvrage, ce qui expliquerait aussi la majuscule à « Catalogue » et l'absence de majuscule à « douze ».